# ffmpeg hls segment name outputting full file path for %03d

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, batch

i am trying to create a batch video converter for windows to convert some of my mkv media to hls the issue i am having is when i try and get segments name index001.ts / index002.ts it does not work instead it keeps returning the full path to the file

```
Invalid segment filename template ''index_D:\HLS\CONVERTED\ENCRYPT-HLS.bat3d.ts'' you can try to use -strftime 1 with it
```

the thing is i have an older batch converter that accepts user input for codecs and bitrates and that works fine using %03d so i am unsure whats broken or wrong in the command because if i take it out of the for loop and run the command on its own it seems to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to represent a single percentage sign % inside a batch script you would have to use double percentage %% inside the batch ex:

Instead of: 'index_%03d.ts'

You use:  'index_%%03d.ts'

Comment: ohh god i didnt even notice that haha shows what a new pair of eyes can do